# Kendo UI: Grid header(width) alignment issue inside tabstrip

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have used KENDO UI two Tabstrips.

1. **Tabstrip One**.
2. **Tabstrip Two**.

and both tabstrip contains a kendo Grid inside and Grid inside **Tabstrip One** is fixed column grid (2 fixed column) and 8 scrollable columns.

**Issue:** The grid inside Tabstrip One will take some 20-30 seconds to load after the page load.

The header of the Grid inside the **Tabstrip One** breaks, If i navigate to **Tabstrip Two** before the grid inside the Tabstrip One loading and comes back to **Tabstrip One** after the grid inside the **Tabstrip One** finished loading. See the First Image.

How every if i click inspect on the Grid header the Grid header comes back to Normal (by self setting the k-grid-header width) See the second Image.

Please let me know if anybody faced similar type of issues.

Thanks in advance

[image: Grid Header is broken]

[image: Grid with normal View]

Comment: Almost fine with the question but how can someone debug your output?

Comment: I would first investigate why it takes so long to load the records in the first grid. Can the select statement be improved? Are you using paging on the grid? If you can, please edit your post and add the select statement and your code for the grid. That will make it easier for us to help you.